# Three Dimensional Array Sum PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want the sum of these 2 arrays.

1st  Array:

```
Array(
[abc] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 20
    [today] => 50
    [tomorrow] => 70
    )

[pqr] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 10
    [today] => 20
    [tomorrow] => 30
    )

[xyz] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 30
    [today] => 20
    [tomorrow] => 10
    )
)
```

2nd Array:

```
Array(
[abc] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 70
    [today] => 20
    [tomorrow] => 50
    )

[pqr] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 20
    [today] => 30
    [tomorrow] => 10
    )

[xyz] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 10
    [today] => 30
    [tomorrow] => 20
    )
)
```

Sum of both arrays:

```
Array(
[abc] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 90
    [today] => 70
    [tomorrow] => 120
    )

[pqr] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 30
    [today] => 50
    [tomorrow] => 40
    )

[xyz] => Array
    (
    [yesterday] => 40
    [today] => 50
    [tomorrow] => 30
    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yep I tried with for loop, but I have hell lot of arrays, so I need a shortcut.

Comment: Then at least show us your attempts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I go through every innerArray of `$arr1` and `$arr2` with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php). Then I go again through every value of the innerArray's and add them together also with `array_map()` after this I combine the returned array with the keys of the innerArray's with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). And at the end I combine the array again with the keys of `$arr1`.

```
<?php

    $arr1 = [
            "abc" => [
                "yesterday" => 20,
                "today" => 50,
                "tomorrow" => 70
            ],
            "pqr" => [
                "yesterday" => 10,
                "today" => 20,
                "tomorrow" => 30
            ],
            "xyz" => [
                "yesterday" => 30,
                "today" => 20,
                "tomorrow" => 10
            ]
        ];

    $arr2 = [
            "abc" => [
                "yesterday" => 70,
                "today" => 20,
                "tomorrow" => 50
            ],
            "pqr" => [
                "yesterday" => 20,
                "today" => 30,
                "tomorrow" => 10
            ],
            "xyz" => [
                "yesterday" => 10,
                "today" => 30,
                "tomorrow" => 20
            ]
        ];  


    $result = array_combine(array_keys($arr1), array_map(function($a1, $a2){
        return array_combine(array_keys($a1), array_map(function($v1, $v2){ return $v1+$v2;}, $a1, $a2));
    }, $arr1, $arr2));


    print_r($result);


?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [abc] => Array
        (
            [yesterday] => 90
            [today] => 70
            [tomorrow] => 120
        )

    [pqr] => Array
        (
            [yesterday] => 30
            [today] => 50
            [tomorrow] => 40
        )

    [xyz] => Array
        (
            [yesterday] => 40
            [today] => 50
            [tomorrow] => 30
        )

)
```

Comment: thanx Rizier123, I wish I could vote up.

Answer (score 2):

```
$b['yesterday'] = array_sum(array_column($a,'yesterday'));
$b['today'] = array_sum(array_column($a,'today'));
...
```

I hope this gives the idea. I know this code is not the end-result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {

    $output[$index]['yesterday'] = ($array2[$index]['yesterday'] + $value['yesterday']);
    $output[$index]['today'] = ($array2[$index]['today'] + $value['today']);
    $output[$index]['tomorrow'] = ($array2[$index]['tomorrow'] + $value['tomorrow']);
}
```

This might not be the prettiest solution, but I think that with this and @Rizier123's solution you might wrap everything in a function and pass 2 arrays at a time with, something like the following function blueprint `function sumArrays($array1, $array2, &output)` and instead of using `=` use `+=`.

Hope this helps!